# first order condition of Lagrangian

Tags: math-mode, equations

Hi can someone please tell me how to write in LaTeX the first order condition of Lagrangian:

[image]

Comment: You have a single derivative in the image?  If this is what you're struggling with you should probably be reading something on typesetting mathematics with latex.  Take a look at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/mathematics.html this will give you a guide on writing basic mathematics, [this page in particular](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/fractions.html) covers most of the necessary parts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use partial derivatives many times. It is better to write a macro:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\newcommand\der[2]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\der{\mathcal{L}_t}{K_t}
\]
\end{document}
```

with the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

You have the `esdiff` package which has a simplified syntax for typesetting derivatives of all orders, in particular for crossed derivatives, and lets you the choice between italic or upright `\partial`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esdiff,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \diffp{\mathcal{L}_t}{K_t}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_t}{\partial K_t}
\end{equation} 
    \end{document}
```